# 2 divs in div. One with %width, one with auto

Tags: css, html, width

```
<div id="one"> 
     <div id="two">
          content
     </div>
     <div id="three">
          content2
     </div>
</div>
```

I've got 3 divs. Two div in one

```
#one { max-width:1000px; }
#two { width:80%; }
#three { min-width:20%; }
```

I want to change attribute display:none; dynamically in wordpress(widget) of #two and then #three should have got width 100%.

How to make it ?

Comment: Did you actually try width:auto on #three? Your css is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to use css table layout. Just change the width of `#two` as you please. When you set `#two`'s display property to `display:none`, `#three` will automatically become 100% as required.

```
#one {
    display:table;
    max-width:1000px;
    width:100%;
}
#two {
    display:table-cell;
    width:80%;
}
#three {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zZAu/)